# Click and drag in Silverlight seems sluggish

Tags: c#, silverlight, graphics, 3d, silverlight-5.0

I have built an entire c# software renderer that is now SilverLight safe (never again), it seems to glitch while trying to rotate the scene via a simple mouse click and drag. It's all a tad complicated but it uses the WriteableBitmap class. Its very quick but it is not smooth.

Take a look http://www.alansimes.com/warp3dsilverlighttestpage.html

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :)

Comment: How are you updating the scene? Are you using timers?